# Absolute positioning - webkit-transition of inner elements

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-position, css-animations

I have a `div` with `position: absolute`:

```
<div class="p1">
    <div class="laser"></div>
    <h2>p1</h2>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.p1{
    position:absolute;
    top:46px;
    left:0px;
    width: 0%;
    height: calc(100% - 46px);
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: width 4s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 4s ease;
    -o-transition: width 4s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 4s ease;
    transition: width 4s ease;
}

.laser{
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    background: #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    top: 46px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

And when I apply `width: 100%` to `div.p1` it animates but without the inner elements moving (they always stay in the same place). Also when `p1` has `width: 0%` I can see its inner content and I don't know why.

EDIT:

Inner elements are not changing position because position is set :). Its enough to remove relative position of laser class and add class pull-right like tihs:

```
<div class="p1">
    <div class="laser pull-right"></div>
    <h2>p1</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen in the animation? You haven't actually specified for any movement to happen.

Comment: 0% -> 100% width. So its going from 0px to 100% of your screen, but without inner elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
.p1{
    position:absolute;
    top:46px;
    left:0px;
    width: 0%;
    height: calc(100% - 46px);
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: width 4s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 4s ease;
    -o-transition: width 4s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 4s ease;
    transition: width 4s ease;
}

.laser{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;   /*You have to change width from 3px to 100% and it will works */
    background: #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    top: 46px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #ff0000;
    z-index: 3;
}
```